# Nginx Rewrite Not working

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I have move my site to nginx but can get .htaccess roules right

below ius my code

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name mysite.com;
root /usr/share/nginx/mysite;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

location / {
rewrite ^/(.*)$ /members.php?id=$1 last;
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

}

location ~ \.php$ {
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi_params;
}
}
```

i want to display user url to be

```
mysite.com/jonny
```

instead of

```
mysite.com/memner.php?id=jonny
```

when i use

```
rewrite ^/(.*)$ /members.php?id=$1 last;
```

site don't load please help.

Comment: Got it fixed thx any way if (!-e $request_filename) {
rewrite /(.*) /members.php?id=$1 last ;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got fix for this

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
rewrite /(.*) /members.php?id=$1 last ;
}
```